# htaccess permanent redirect to home page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to write a rule in htaccess that always redirects `http://example.com/index.aspx` or `http://www.example.com/index.aspx` to `http://example.com`.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.aspx [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1 [R=301,L]
```

but it's not working properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just one rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.aspx$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to avoid writing the domain name somehow?

Comment: Yes, without www, or as in the URL ?

Comment: I edit the rule with the same host used in the initial URL